# jQuery toggle div and text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

I would like some help with this code, I have read similar questions & answers here on stackoverflow but I still can't get it right.

I have a link that populated by .html("") to read `more…`

when clicked it opens the hidden div and at the end the .html("") reads `less...`

When I click close, the div slides closed but the text still reads `less...`

I have read many articles on how to do this but am confused and can't get past this last hurdle, any help would be much appreciated.

// this is the intro div

```
<div id="" class="">
    <p>
        Ligula suspendisse nulla pretium, rhoncus tempor placerat fermentum, enim
        integer ad vestibulum volutpat. Nisl rhoncus turpis est, vel elit, congue
        wisi enim nunc ultricies sit, magna tincidunt. Maecenas aliquam maecenas
        ligula nostra, accumsan taciti.
   </p> 
</div>
```

// this next div is hidden

```
<div class="overview-continued"> 
    <p>
        Ligula suspendisse nulla pretium, rhoncus tempor placerat fermentum, enim
        integer ad vestibulum volutpat. Nisl rhoncus turpis est, vel elit, congue
        wisi enim nunc ultricies sit, magna tincidunt. Maecenas aliquam maecenas
        ligula nostra, accumsan taciti.
    </p>
</div>

<a class="show-overview" href="#"><h4></h4></a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".overview-continued").hide();
    $(".show-overview").html("more...");
    $(".show-overview").click(function() {
        $(".overview-continued").slideToggle("1000");
        $(".show-overview").html("less...");
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example on jsfiddle.net of the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You are only ever setting it to `less..`. You also need to evaluate it and set it back to `more...` if the current value is `less...`.

See [**DEMO: Comparing HTML**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/5rZVr/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".overview-continued").hide();
    $(".show-overview").html("more...");
    $(".show-overview").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(".overview-continued").slideToggle("1000");
        $(".show-overview").html(text == "less..." ? "more..." : "less...");
        return false;
    });
});​
```

**Edit**
`freakish` mentioned in the comments that comparing HTMLs is bad practice.
(Also updated samples to use the text and tags as specified by OP)

To that end, see alternative [**DEMO: Using Attributes**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/BFq4t/1/)

The `anchor` received a new custom attribute:

```
<a class="show-overview" data-item-state="showLess">...</a>​
```

Script is updated and a little re-factored too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".overview-continued").hide();

    setState();

    $(".show-overview").click(function() {
        $(".overview-continued").slideToggle("1000");
        setState();
        return false;
    });

    function setState() {
        var control = $(".show-overview");
        var state = control.attr("data-item-state");

        control.html(state == "showLess" ? "more..." : "less...");
        control.attr("data-item-state", state == "showLess" ? "showMore" : "showLess");
    };
});​
```

Comment: This works indeed, but comparing HTMLs? This is bad practice.

Comment: @freakish: Thank you for the comment. I went with the simplest solution to start and OP can re-factor I guess. However, I added an alternative to comparing HTML. That should get the OP started into the right direction. The main thing for the OP to keep in mind is that if you want to switch between states or values you need to evaluate each time and set accordingly.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes, of course. I just believe that precise answers are not good enough - we should always teach people about good practices. :)

Comment: @freakish +1 on that comment. I agree. I usualy try to answer first with a working solution and sometimes go back and re-factor it to use better approaches. Thank you again though for mentioning it as it is important to pass on good practices off course.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a conditional in your click function because you are always setting .show-overview to "less..."

May not be the correct syntax but:

```
$(".show-overview").click(function()

    {
        $(".overview-continued").slideToggle("1000");
        if($(".show-overview").html() == "less...")
        {
        $(".show-overview").html("more...");
        }
        else
        {
        $(".show-overview").html("less...");
        }
        return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to know when the `div` is opened/closed from JavaScript point of view. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var overview = $(".overview-continued");
    overview.hide();
    var show = $(".show-overview");
    show.html("more...");
    show.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var is_opened = overview.data('is_opened');
        if (!is_opened) {
            overview.slideDown(500, function() {
                show.html("less...");
            });
        } else {
            overview.slideUp(500, function() {
                show.html("more...");
            });
        }
        overview.data('is_opened', !is_opened);
    });
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yJz9/2/) code. Note that I refactored your code a bit.

Comment: Not sure about the -1. Seems someone downvoted all the answers at the start for some reason.   +1 here anyway as it is a working solution.

Comment: Thanks freakish, this is very good code for me to learn on, works perfectly in jsfiddle but for some reason it won't work for me on xampp or my live site. I'll have to see if there is some kind of conflict but it's a small site in development so not much code. PS I couldn't +1 as I am not yet permitted but when I can I will.

Comment: You get a few points for accepting an answer which should get you to the required 15 points I think.

Comment: @Jack If you are using Chrome or FireFox, then you can check errors in console (CTRL+SHIFT+J). New versions of IE have console as well (F12? not sure though). Then you will know why it isn't working (probably there are conflicts OR you've loaded really old jQuery version). :)

Comment: I just read up on the `jQuery.data()` object again and think you using the `data` object is very nice. Seeing that this is the intend of the `data` object. Quote from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/: `Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element.` Just thought I mention it.

Answer (score 0):

you are telling it right there in the click-function to label it with ".less".
it would make it easier to understand, if you split it up in two methods...
something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function close(){  
      $(".overview-continued").slideToggle("1000");
      $(".show-overview").html("more...");
    }
    function open(){  
      $(".overview-continued").slideToggle("1000");
      $(".show-overview").html("less...");
    }
    $(".overview-continued").hide();
    $(".show-overview").toggle(open,close);
});​
```

edit: due to comments

Comment: Without `unbind` this will add handlers each time you click making slide toggle multiple times (and html exchanging as well).